# How do I set the background color for a active caption frame with wxpython or wxformbuilder

Tags: wxpython, wxformbuilder

I'm new to wxpython and I'm using wxformbuilder to design most of the my forms but I'm unable to determine how to set background color for the active caption in my frame ?  Do I do this in code or is there a property within wxformbuilder I can set ?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can set background color for your active frame from both wxformbuilder RAD evironment and also from within wxpython code.

**To set background color via wxformbuilder**

Add your Frame >> Sizer >> Panel on the "Object tree" and set the background (bg) color from the "Object Properties" pane to the right hand side. See the image below for details.
[image]

**To set background color via wxpython code**

Use the "SetBackgroundColour" and "wx.Colour" methods of the panel to set its color property.

```
self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
self.m_panel1.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 128, 0 ) )
```

See the complete code below:-

```
import wx

class MyFrame1 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_panel1 = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_panel1.SetBackgroundColour( wx.Colour( 255, 128, 0 ) )

        bSizer1.Add( self.m_panel1, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame1(None).Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.  What I really need is a way to change the background color of the active caption for the frame (where the title appears).  I know it's a windows system property but there doesn't appear to be a way to change it in the GUI designer or within wxpython code.

Comment: I see, this will depend on the OS or so?